# ControlsFx SpreadsheetView Span

Tags: java, controlsfx

I am using `SpreadSheetView` of `ControlsFX`,

With that i am able to span rows/columns using the `GridBase` utility method like below,

```
getGrid().spanColumn(2, row, column);
```

Now, i want to remove this span and revert it to original .

How can i do that ?

Answer (score 1):

I must confess I have not thought of anybody wanting to remove the span..

When you span some cells, the first cell is copied and pasted into the place of others in order to reflect the fact that it is spanning. Therefore, the previous cells are trashed. So the operation cannot be reverted.

But you could reverse the process by reducing the span value of the initial cell, and adding new proper cell in the places where the span is not present anymore.

Don't hesitate to post on our google group to have quicker response : https://groups.google.com/forum/?hl=en#!forum/controlsfx-dev